# ElasticSearch 6.7 document creation time

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, kibana

I want each document that I store into my ES index to have a creation time by default like datetime.now (NOT set by the client who sends the PUT request but set by the ES itself). Is there a way to do that? Or do I have to pass the value during indexing my document in PUT request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)  and [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/script-processor.html).

The following example create a pipeline `set_creation_date` adding the document date of creation in the `created_at` field.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/set_creation_date
{
    "description": "Set creation date",
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "source": "ctx.created_at = new Date();"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

When you index a document **add the name of the pipeline in the `pipeline` query param**.

```
POST /my_index/_doc?pipeline=set_creation_date
{
   // Your doc...
}
```

For this to work, you must have at least one ingest node.